# How to run a springboot application using C++ jni environment

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to run a springboot application jar file using C++ jni lib using the following code:

```
void init_jni() {
    const int kNumOptions = 1;
    JavaVMOption options[kNumOptions] = {
            {const_cast<char *>("-Djava.class.path=app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"), nullptr},
    };

    JavaVMInitArgs vmArgs = {
            JNI_VERSION_1_8, kNumOptions, options, JNI_TRUE
    };

    // Create the JVM
    JavaVM *javaVM;
    JNIEnv *jniEnv;

    long flag = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&javaVM, (void **) &jniEnv, &vmArgs);


    if (flag == JNI_ERR) {
        cout << "Error creating VM. Exiting...\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    jclass jcls = jniEnv->FindClass("org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher");

    if (jcls == nullptr) {
        jniEnv->ExceptionDescribe();
        javaVM->DestroyJavaVM();
        exit(1);
    }

    jmethodID methodId = jniEnv->GetStaticMethodID(jcls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    if (methodId == nullptr) {
        jniEnv->ExceptionDescribe();
        javaVM->DestroyJavaVM();
        exit(1);
    }


    jniEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(jcls, methodId);

    if (jniEnv->ExceptionCheck()) {
        jniEnv->ExceptionDescribe();
        jniEnv->ExceptionClear();
    }


    javaVM->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

I'm getting a java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException when I call the `init_jni` method above.
Running `java -jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` works fine via terminal.
Is there anything else I'm supposed to do?

Here is the exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: java.lang.Class
    at java.lang.Object.clone(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.<init>(MainMethodRunner.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.createMainMethodRunner(Launcher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: @MrBin Not yet. I ended up using another alternative which was nasty but would love to use this approach

Comment: Why do you call `org.springframework.boot.loader.jarlauncher` instead your static main app function?

Comment: @MrBin Coz usually the main class is in `/BOOT-INF/classes/` which can't be ran. And also `org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher` is usually spring boot's main class right?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from @Mister_Jeusu's comment, I tried this. It worked for me.

```
int RunSpring(JavaVM * jvm, JNIEnv * env)
{
        /* Run app */

        jclass class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher");
        if (!class)
        {
                PRINT_LINENO;
                return -1;
        }

        jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, class, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
        if (!mid)
        {
                PRINT_LINENO;
                return -1;
        }

        (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, class, mid, NULL);

        return 0;
}
```